# How to set default selected dates for Calendar Control in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

How to have default dates selected from odata for the calendar control. I tried a jsbin. 
it says the default aggregation need to filled before adding child.

```
<u:Calendar id="calendar" select="handleCalendarSelect" singleSelection="false" selectedDates="{path:'/selectedDates'>
            <u:DateRange startDate="{startDate}"/>
            </u:Calendar>
```

https://jsbin.com/yurikay/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted aggregation tag `<u:selectedDates>`

```
  <u:Calendar
            id="calendar"
            selectedDates="{path: '/selectedDates'}"
            singleSelection="false"
            select="handleCalendarSelect" >
              <u:selectedDates>
                <u:DateRange startDate="{startDate}" />
              </u:selectedDates>
            </u:Calendar>
```

Working example:
https://jsbin.com/zupecihiye/1/edit?html